# How to SELECT using Group statement in MYSQL, multiple attributes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to SELECT the employee id, name, hired date, etc of the supervisors, and the total number of employees directly supervised by each one of them. And display only those records that supervised 8 or more employees.

This is what I used to get the result below

````
select supervisor_id, COUNT(supervisor_id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY supervisor_id
HAVING COUNT(supervisor_id) >= 8; 

``` Result
+---------------+----------------------+
| supervisor_id | COUNT(supervisor_id) |
+---------------+----------------------+
|           100 |                   14 |
|           120 |                    8 |
|           121 |                    8 |
|           122 |                    8 |
|           123 |                    8 |
|           124 |                    8 |
+---------------+----------------------+

what I wanted to write was: 

SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary COUNT(supervisor_id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY supervisor_id, 
HAVING COUNT(supervisor_id) >= 8;
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table to a query that returns the supervisor ids and the number of employees supervised by each of them:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.hire_date, e.salary, s.counter
FROM employee e INNER JOIN (
   SELECT supervisor_id, COUNT(*) counter
   FROM employee
   GROUP BY supervisor_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 8
) s on s.supervisor_id = e.employee_id
```

Comment: @TryPenta the answer that you accepted does not return *the total number of employees* supervised by each supervisor as you set the requirement.

Comment: ah yes. Is there anyway to show the total employees supervised?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes it actually works too, but i think its a little bit too high level for my understanding

Comment: what does adding a e. mean to my attirbutes?

Comment: `e` is the alias of the table EMPLOYEE and `s` is the alias of the subquery. Joins and aliases are the basics of SQL. So get used to them.

Answer (score 0):

To list the employees which have a supervisor which has more than 8 employees:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary, supervisor_id
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE supervisor_id IN (
   select supervisor_id
   FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY supervisor_id
   HAVING COUNT(supervisor_id) >= 8);
```

To list the supervisor which have more than 8 employees:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary, supervisor_id
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE employee_id IN (
   select supervisor_id
   FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY supervisor_id
   HAVING COUNT(supervisor_id) >= 8);
HAVING COUNT(supervisor_id) >= 8;
```

Comment: I tried that and got ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(supervisor_id)

Comment: oops, delete the COUNT(supervisor), I will update my answer.....

Comment: Ok, thanks! It works but it is not what i wanted though,

Comment: aah, you wanted to list the supervisors, not the epmployees….   

Comment: Yes! Its quite close but still I am looking for something like merged version of supervisor ID like the result I provided above

Comment: btw is there anyway to show the totaled number of employees being supervised?

Comment: I think that the solution @forpas gave you does do that. With this solution the count can only be added using a subquery